# Crossserver SQL Procedures Failing Mid Process

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server

Really need help understanding whats happening. We have two LANs at work with a shared subnet between them acting as a bridge (migration from A > B underway) we recently migrated the server subnet from the old LAN to the new one and are now experiencing issues that are causing scheduled jobs that reach out to COLO servers to mirror data (both directions) to fail. Sometimes they fail upfront, sometimes they fail mid process, and sometimes they just work (not often). The problem is extremely unpredictable and inconsistent. Any thoughts? Where can I check?

SQL2000 reaching out to SQL2005, 2008, and mySQL.

Not a firewall issue nor a route issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upstream **firewall was blocking P2P connections** which can look like SQL remote connections.